# how to create a vector of equally-spaced values from a dataset in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a set of data as follows:

dataset 1

```
z            x           v           y       d                p
19.88000     8.06411     5.46210     1.26122 1000000.000      13.484       
20.13000     8.23777     5.71589     1.26241 1000000.000      13.774       
20.38000     8.38748     5.98116     1.26355 1000000.000      14.024      
20.63000     8.54422     6.24602     1.26465 1000000.000      14.286 
20.88000     8.70251     6.51180     1.26571 1000000.000      14.551
```

dataset2

```
z            x           v           y       d                p
19.13000     7.27788     4.79292     1.16700 1000000.000      11.639 
19.38000     7.45097     5.05959     1.16845 1000000.000      11.915   
19.63000     7.60064     5.34092     1.16984 1000000.000      12.155 
20.88000     8.33493     7.09921     1.17608 1000000.000      13.329
21.00500     8.39859     7.22789     1.17665 1000000.000      14.151
```

I read the data from several .txt file and combine them to get a vector containing z values (first column) and another vector containing x values(second column). But i have several of these. First I thought about averaging different z and x vectors. But unfortunately, z values are not equally spaced (meaning that in one dataset, z vector goes like 19.88, 20.13, 20.38 and so on. However in another dataset, z goes like 19.54, 20.22, 20.87 and so on..) So i need a way of creating equally spaced bins for vector z.

In other words, I have multiple vectors of z values and I want to create another vector where it goes like 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5 ....In bins of 0.5, I want to average values in z vectors and do the same for corresponding x vectors. What i want to have is as follows:

```
z            x          
19.00        7.36
19.50        7.83   
20.00        8.31
20.50        8.53
21.00        8.39
```

Here, 7.36 is average of 7.27788 and 7.45097 since their z values are between 19.00 and 19.50. Similarly, 7.83 is average of 7.60064 and 8.06411 because their z values are between 19.50 and 20.00 and so on.

Is there a smart way to do that in R?
Because my datasets have different length and I don't want to write a for loop to check each element.

Comment: `aggregate(c(d1$x, d2$x), list(z = findInterval(c(d1$z, d2$z), seq(19, 22, .5))), mean)` or `aggregate(c(d1$x, d2$x), list(z = cut(c(d1$z, d2$z), breaks = seq(19, 22, .5))), mean)` which you could use `labels=` for nicer labels

Comment: useful ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364679/r-calculate-the-average-of-one-column-corresponding-to-each-bin-of-another-colum   ...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108980/r-aggregate-data-in-one-column-based-on-2-other-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach built around [`floor()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html). It divides `z` by the interval size 0.5, then calls `floor()`, then multiplies by 0.5 to get the lower bound of the interval which contains each value (as per your required output). It then aggregates all non-`z` columns on the transformed `z` column to get the means.

Since you have multiple input data sets, I also use [`ls()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ls.html) with the `pattern` option, [`mget()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html), and the [`do.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html)+[`rbind()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) idiom to first combine all input data sets into one data.frame.

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(z=c(19.88000,20.13000,20.38000,20.63000,20.88000),x=c(8.06411,8.23777,8.38748,8.54422,8.70251),v=c(5.46210,5.71589,5.98116,6.24602,6.51180),y=c(1.26122,1.26241,1.26355,1.26465,1.26571),d=c(1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000),p=c(13.484,13.774,14.024,14.286,14.551));
dataset2 <- data.frame(z=c(19.13000,19.38000,19.63000,20.88000,21.00500),x=c(7.27788,7.45097,7.60064,8.33493,8.39859),v=c(4.79292,5.05959,5.34092,7.09921,7.22789),y=c(1.16700,1.16845,1.16984,1.17608,1.17665),d=c(1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000,1000000.000),p=c(11.639,11.915,12.155,13.329,14.151));
aggregate(.~z,transform(do.call(rbind,mget(ls(pattern='^dataset\\d+$'))),z=floor(z/0.5)*0.5),mean);
##      z        x        v        y     d        p
## 1 19.0 7.364425 4.926255 1.167725 1e+06 11.77700
## 2 19.5 7.832375 5.401510 1.215530 1e+06 12.81950
## 3 20.0 8.312625 5.848525 1.262980 1e+06 13.89900
## 4 20.5 8.527220 6.619010 1.235480 1e+06 14.05533
## 5 21.0 8.398590 7.227890 1.176650 1e+06 14.15100
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps instead of averaging the two values, you should use a linear model to do the work.

Where your second data set is `d2`, you can do this:

```
m <- lm(x ~ z, data=d2)
z <- seq(from=19,to=21,by=.5)
data.frame(z=z, x=predict(m, data.frame(z=z)))
##      z        x
## 1 19.0 7.216522
## 2 19.5 7.513079
## 3 20.0 7.809636
## 4 20.5 8.106194
## 5 21.0 8.402751
```

These aren't actual averages as you asked, but perhaps are useful for what you really need.

Comment: I'd prefer actual values but what you suggest is cool, thanks